# how to deserialize json string with arrays

Tags: json, http, httpclient

Res :

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Security Questions fetched Successfully",
  "data": [

    [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "what is u r name?",
          "category": "personel"
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "what is your nick name?",
          "category": "personnal"
        },
    ], 
    [
        {
          "id": 43,
          "name": "what is your spouse name?",
          "category": "family"
        },
        {
          "id": 42,
          "name": "what is your nick name?",
          "category": "family"
        }
    ]

  ]
}
```

Comment: Res : 

{
  "status": "success",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Security Questions fetched Successfully",
  "data": [
 
 [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "what is u r name?",
    "category": "personel"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "what is your nick name?",
    "category": "personnal"
  },
 ], 
 [
  {
    "id": 43,
    "name": "what is your spouse name?",
    "category": "family"
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "what is your nick name?",
    "category": "family"
  }
 ]
  
  ]
}

Comment: Add some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: i am using::


 var questionslist = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Res>(questionslist);

Comment: i am using::


 var questionslist = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Res>(questionslist);

Comment: i am using:  

  
        public class Res  

   {

        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<dataQlist> data { get; set; }
      
    }


    public class dataQlist
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
       

    }

for deserialize:

    var questionslist = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                  
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Res>(questionslist);

please provide solution for this